# Does Windows 10 file Indexing affect programs?

Tags: windows-10, search-indexing

Or is it limited only to searches done via File Explorer?

If I changed Indexing Options, could it have made programs loading tens of thousands of small files take longer time to load?

Edit: Or is it vice versa? Adding those tens of thousands of files to the Indexer creates an overload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't. Loading lots of small files is lots of overhead. Indexing will stop while you do that or use the computer in any way.

Computers have the concept of taxes. Where is overhead levied. In Windows overhead is levied on process creation and window creation. Files are slow by nature and overhead is levied there too, files overhead is levied when you open it. Lots of files is lots of overhead. Programs are always waiting for files.